# fatal error: Index out of range swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing Index out of range issue in UITableView.
Below is my code :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    //== Teble: number of tables ==============================//
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return headerTitleArray.count
    }
 //== Teble rows: number of rows ==============================//
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return cellTitleMultiArray.count
    }

    //== Teble rows: data for each row ==============================//
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let text = cellTitleMultiArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = text
        return cell
    }


}
```

I am trying to solve this issue but couldn't .Please please help me solve this issue....

Comment: Is this correct `return cellTitleMultiArray.count`? Does sounds like what you want. I think it should be `return cellTitleMultiArray[section].count`

Comment: `return cellTitleMultiArray.count` => `return cellTitleMultiArray[indexPath.section].count`

Comment: I tried cellTitleMultiArray[section].count also but it crashs

Comment: Just *think:* If `cellTitleMultiArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` is what you need for a given row in a given section, what should numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection return? (Both are wrong in your code)

Comment: So what should it return?

Comment: Thank you @MartinR i corrected my code

Comment: numberOfSections should be cellTitleMultiArray.count and the other one was given by Larme. Also why don't you try debugging or printing out the interesting values?

Comment: Double check your cellTitleMultiArray, headerTitleArray counts

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `cellTitleMultiArray` is an array of arrays, where the outer array contains an entry for each section, and for each section, the inner array at that index contains entries for each row in that section.

Thus `numberOfSections(in:)` should probably return the number of entries in `cellTitleMultiArray`.

`tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` should probably return the number of entries in the `cellTitleMultiArray` sub-array at the current section. See if you can work out that bit of code.

Comment: I have a viewForHeaderInSection: where should i call the return value of array?